# Looking for a cleaner way to run a query that has to check for multiple "AND" conditions

Tags: mysql

I'm running a query against a database and have to check for multiple conditions to be true.  The code I have pulls the data I want, but if I had to check many more columns, it could get out of control very quickly.  I don't want a query that where I have to write out a dozen or so "AND" conditions.  I'm learning some MySQL as I go and any help would be appreciated.

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "oldga740_SeniorProject";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//Set up and run my Query

$sql = "SELECT Project, Client, DateReceived, LastName, FinalReviewDate FROM Projects
          WHERE FinalReviewDate IS NOT NULL
          AND DateDelivered IS NULL
          AND DateAccepted IS NULL
          ORDER BY DateAccepted DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//Display results

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 echo "<table><tr><th>Client</th><th>Project</th><th>Point of     Contact</th><th>Date Project Received</th><th>Final Review Date</th></tr>";
 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Client"]. "</td><td>" . $row    ["Project"]. "</td><td> " . $row["LastName"]. "</td><td> " . $row    ["DateReceived"]. "</td><td> " . $row["FinalReviewDate"]. "</td></tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
} else {
 echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array for your and conditions. But in general you have to be careful if you are going to have prepared statements and bind values. Also, you can create your `WHERE` clause dynamically in a similar way like the following:

EDIT:

```
$where = array(
    array(
        'column'=>'FinalReviewDate',
        'operator'=>'AND',
        'condition'=>'IS NOT NULL',
        'value'=>'',
    ),
    array(
        'column'=>'DateDelivered',
        'operator'=>'AND',
        'condition'=>'IS NULL',
        'value'=>'',
    ),
    array(
        'column'=>'DateAccepted',
        'operator'=>'AND',
        'condition'=>'IS NULL',
        'value'=>'',
    ),
    array(
        'column'=>'other_column',
        'operator'=>'OR',
        'condition'=>'>=',
        'value'=>5,
    ),
);

$temp = array();

foreach($where as $key => $value) {
if ($value['value'] == '') {
        $temp[] = $value['operator'].' '.$value['column'].' '.$value['condition'];
    } else {
        $temp[] = $value['operator'].' '.$value['column'].' '.$value['condition'].' '.$value['value'];
    }
}

$where_sql = '1 = 1 '.implode(' ', $temp);

echo $where_sql;
```

Result:

```
1 = 1 AND FinalReviewDate IS NOT NULL AND DateDelivered IS NULL AND DateAccepted IS NULL OR other_column >= 5
```

OLD ANSWER

```
$ands = array(
    array(
        'column'=>'FinalReviewDate',
        'condition'=>'IS NOT NULL'
    ),
    array(
        'column'=>'DateDelivered',
        'condition'=>'IS NULL'
    ),
    array(
        'column'=>'DateAccepted',
        'condition'=>'IS NULL'
    ),
);

$temp = array();

foreach($ands as $key => $value) {
    $temp[] = $value['column'].' '.$value['condition'];
}

$and_sql = implode(' AND ', $temp);

echo $and_sql;
```

Result:

```
FinalReviewDate IS NOT NULL AND DateDelivered IS NULL AND DateAccepted IS NULL
```

Comment: where in the code would I place the array?  I'm assuming it would replace the WHERE and two AND statements...

Comment: You can place the array just above the $sql variable. It replaces the following: FinalReviewDate IS NOT NULL
          AND DateDelivered IS NULL
          AND DateAccepted IS NULL

Comment: Is there a benefit to the array over the lines of code I already have, or is it a preferred practice?  My largest table only has 9 columns and four of them are filled in whenever a new entry is made into the table.

Comment: It depends on the situation. When i make a query dynamically that depends on the user input i follow the array approach. But if you have only 4-5 columns that always will be filled up then i think that it's a bit over complicated.

Comment: The queries are run by onclick events and I'm only going to have 5 that would require multiple AND statements.  I'm building a separate form to allow the user to input initial and updated data into the database.  Some of the columns are going to be NULL values depending on where in the process the data has been input.  I like the array idea though.  I can see where it would be helpful if my database was larger, but it's for a school project so I'm keeping it smaller on purpose.

Comment: Yes, you can keep this idea at the back of your mind.

Comment: I appreciate all of your help this afternoon!  I'll definitely keep your array in mind on larger projects.